# Low accuracy of DNN created using tf.keras on dataset having small feature set

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

`total train data record: 460000`

`total cross-validation data record: 89000`

`number of output class: 392`

`tensorflow 1.8.0 CPU installation`

Each data record has 26 features, where 25 are numeric and one is categorical which is one hot encoded into 19 additional features. Initially, not all feature value was present for each data record. I have used avg to fill missing float type features and most frequent value for missing int type feature. Output can be any of 392 classes labeled as 0 to 391.

Finally, all features are passed through a `StandardScaler()`

Here is my model:

```python
output_class = 392
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = get_data()

# y_train and y_test contains int from 0-391    
# Make y_train and y_test categorical
y_train = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, unique_dtc_count)
y_test = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, unique_dtc_count)

# Convert to float type
y_train = y_train.astype(np.float32)
y_test = y_test.astype(np.float32)

# tf.enable_eager_execution()  # turned off to use rmsprop optimizer

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(400, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape= 
(44,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(40000, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(392, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=3)

loss, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('Accuracy', acc)
```

But this model gives only 28% accuracy on both on training and test data. What should I change here to get a good accuracy on both training and test data? Should I go wider and deeper? Or should I consider taking more features?

---

**Note:** there were total 400 unique features in the dataset. But most of the features only appeared randomly in 5 to 10 data record. And some features have no relevance in other data records. I picked 26 features based on domain knowledge and frequency in data records.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

---

**EDIT**: I forgot to add this in the original post, @Neb suggested a less wide deeper network, I actually tried this. My first model was a [44,400,400,392] layer. It gave me around 30% accuracy in training and testing.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is too wider. You have **400** nodes in the first hidden layer and **40.000** in the second layer, for a total of 400*44 + 40.000*400 + 392*400 = **16.174.400** parameters. However, you only input 44 features!

Because of this, your net is capable of detecting even the smallest, most imperceptible variations in inputs and finally it considers them as valuable information instead of noise. I'm quite sure that if you leave your network training for a long time (here I only see 3 epoch), it will end up with overfitting your training set.

You have some solutions:

1. reduce the number of nodes per levels. You may also experiment adding 1 or 2 new layers. A possible structure might be `[44, 128, 512, 392]`
2. Implement regression. You have multiple way to do this:

   - restrict the range the range in which network parameters live
   - implement Dropout
   - implement Batch normalization (which is known to have a small regularization effect)
3. use Adam Optimizer instead of RMSprop
4. If your features are somewhat correlated, you may try a CNN instead of a Fully connected network.

Then, to improve generalization you can:

1. explore the dataset looking for outliers and remove them. An outlier is a sample which can confuse the network or does not convey any additional information.
2. "randomly" initialize your parameters, e.g using Xavier's Initialization

Finally, I would say: do you really need 392 classes? Could you merge some of them?

Comment: ,thanks for your reply, you said it right, as I have only 44 features, and 392 classes to predict, I went for a wide network. My intension was to capture detail informations about the parameters.
previously I went for [44, 400, 400, 393] layer with 3 epochs it gave me ~30% accuracy. 

I'm afraid parameters are not co-related. And output classess are not mergable too. you can think output classess as diagnostics code for patients.

I will implement your other suggestions though. Let's see how it affects the network. Cheers.

Comment: Ok, also try to train the net for more epochs.